# Cocos2d-js EditBox Undefined

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I am having an issue with Cocos2d-js, where it doesn't seem to think that cc.EditBox exists. I create a new project and try to delcare:

```
var box = cc.EditBox.create(...)
```

And I get this error in my browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
```

I cannot figure out why this would be the case. Within the project directory I can even see that `frameworks/cocos2d-html5/extensions/editbox` exists and contains the files `CCdomNode.js` and `CCEditBox.js`.

Does anyone have an explanation and/or solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common error, the problem is that `EditBox` is an optional module.

You need to add `"editbox"` to the `modules` list in your game's `project.json` file, and then `cc.EditBox` will be defined.

Like this

```
"modules": [
  "cocos2d",
  "cocostudio",
  "editbox"
],
```